# Save database files in jar

Tags: java, database

Some context: I'm creating an application that would let a user add databases files to it. The user would then query and/or update those databases (using sqlite3) from the app. The database files would preferably be stored together with the classes of the program in a package called 'databases'.

**Problem**: if a user wishes to add a database to the program, the user has to select a database file on his/her computer and that file would then get copied over into the package 'databases'. I do not know how I can copy files from the computer into the program. All help is appreciated.

Questions:

- How can I copy database files from a computer into a package of the program.
- Is this a decent method of achieving my goal, or is it entirely backwards and another method should be preferred?

Comment: why not just use a properties file to configure the db if they want to use it?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense, a program is read only you don't modify it after release unless you are crazy, the data that the program handle has to be somewhere else.

Comment: Answer - don't.  If the database files were added to the Jar, they'd be read-only ... if the JDBC driver was capable of loading them at all.  I don't see why you need the database files stored anywhere other then where they already are - you simply want to store a reference to them in some kind of configuration file.  If you really want to "copy" them, then put them in a well known location, for example, `~/Library/Application Support/{you app name}` on Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would ever store user data in the same jar as the program itself. Data and program code is best kept separate. If you just want to "import" the database into the app, you should have your app pick a directory on the computer where all databases are kept. When the users adds a new database, you should then copy it into that directory from wherever it is imported.